# Image is being save to the folder in db but other information is not being save

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

Need help above code is saving image to a folder(photos) define in the above code. but the other data which is being post by a form is not being save to database...I am new to php and i found this code from a website www.jeasyui.com. so i try to modified it but fail..as usual.:(

```
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

        $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $name = $_REQUEST['prname'];
        $code = $_REQUEST['prcode'];
        $type = $_REQUEST['prtype'];
        $weight = $_REQUEST['prweight'];
        $desc = $_REQUEST['prdesc'];
        $machine = $_REQUEST['prmachinemodel'];
include 'conn.php';
$sql = "insert into canon (product_name,product_code,product_type, product_descp, product_weight, machine_model, location) values('$name','$code','$type','$desc',$weight','$machine','$location')";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
} else {
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
}}?>
```

Comment: Sorry the conn.php is as follow.
<?php

$conn = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$conn) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('opt_systm', $conn);

?>

Comment: Why do you have that @ there thats just hiding the error message if there is one :p

Comment: So the photo gets ploaded correctly, but the database insert fails?

Comment: @lemondrop Hm u r right i will remove it and try..

Comment: @JayRizzi Yes! i am facing this problem.

Comment: @lemodrop i remove "@" and also added a line after sql query ends -->
or  die('Could not Insert data: ' . mysql_error());
but nothing happens only again the image save but other data does not saved..

Answer (score 0):

Use POST or GET instead REQUEST first of all.
Then what happens if you do a var_dump of the $sql, than try to execute it in phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: again same problem i replace REQUEST with POST nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the code, then make sure you have html inputs with these names:prname,prcode,prtype,prweight,prdesc,prmachinemodel

Comment: hm. i will check it again.

Comment: print_r($_POST)  to see what comes with post :D.